# Not able to fill dropdown By json converted dataset

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

I am trying to fill dropdown by json converted dataset  But I am getting this error

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
```

this is function :

```
  function GetDropDownData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ClassTouch.aspx/GetDropDownDataWM",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    response=json.parse(response);

                    for (var i = 0; i < response.Table.length; i++) {
                        $("<option>").val(response.Table[i]['Id'])
                                     .text(response.Table[i]['UserName'])
                                     .appendTo($("#ddlLecturer"));
                    }

                }

            });
```

this is webMethod :

```
public static string GetDropDownDataWM()
 {
    //fill dataset from DB

    DataRow toInsert = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    toInsert[0] = 1;
    toInsert[1] = "None";
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(toInsert, 0);

   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

I know it must be some conversion , But I could not able to find right solution after searching .. What Am I missing ?

Comment: I guess `response.Table` in your JS should be `response.Tables`. Also, you dont need `json.parse(..)`

Comment: can you add the response here.

Comment: where are you getting this error? At server side or at client side at browser level?